# Change alpha channel in MOV file in Sony Vegas?

Tags: video-editing

I’ve been trying to look all over the internet but haven’t found a solution. I have a MOV file with a transparent background. How do I change the alpha channel to a solid color in Sony Vegas Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Add a second track with a solid color below your existing MOV.
This should do it.